# How to live check element inset html with jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, live

I have some block with dinamicly parsing content. I need to change some style for it but if there is some html. My question: is there any possible to live check with jQuery that some element have html at specify moment and set some actions if it's for example empty? Thx for some information.

My code:

```
if ($('.degrees').live().html === ("")){
    $('.block').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

to detect divs that were empty and got their html changed:

```
$('.degrees:empty').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    //...
});
```

to detect every html change

```
$('.degrees').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
    if($(this).is(':empty')) // check if it became empty ..
});
```

Comment: ohhh yeah, it's work, much thx! i'm thinking about this whole evening

Answer (score 0):

You can check it this way:

```
if($('.degrees').html().length > 0){
    // element has children
} else {
    // no children
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is empty like so:

```
if ($('.degrees').is(':empty')){
    $('.block').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

but it will only work when you do the check, and not for future elements, to do that you would have to use an interval to check it regularly, and that's generally not a good idea.

Comment: ok, but this will fire up in one moment, i have a lot of content dinamicly loaded with ajax in to .degrees block, i need to checking live this element :(

Answer (score 0):

You can check the children element:

```
var $main = $('.degrees'),
    $child = $('.block');

if($main.children().length < 0) {
    $child.fadeOut(500);
}
```